# Как сохранить пропорции блока растянутого на всю ширину экрана с изображением внутри

Tags: css

Есть вот такой пример кода:

```css
#first_picture {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6--dahlia-flowers-summer-flowers.jpg);
  /* здесь нужно задать ширину равной ширине экрана и при этом сохранить высоту порпорционально ширине этого изображения */
}

#second_picture {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/70/32/bb/7032bbee082daf62708332df63af9c5b--two-hearts-sweet-hearts.jpg);
  /* здесь нужно задать ширину равной ширине экрана и при этом сохранить высоту порпорционально ширине этого изображения */
}
```

```html
<div id="first_picture"></div>
<div id="second_picture"></div>
```

нужно для каждого блока задать ширину равной ширине экрана и при этом сохранить его высоту пропорционально ширине изображения внутри него (background)

Comment: Вроде бы для этих целей тег `img` придумали. Или обязательно использовать `background`?

Answer (score 2):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
.img-block{
  position:relative;
}
.img-block__content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<h2>Без контента внутри</h2>

<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6--dahlia-flowers-summer-flowers.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/70/32/bb/7032bbee082daf62708332df63af9c5b--two-hearts-sweet-hearts.jpg" alt="" />

<h2>С контентом</h2>

<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6--dahlia-flowers-summer-flowers.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="img-block__content">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, nihil, sed officiis quas voluptatem sit similique quae ullam neque quod.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/70/32/bb/7032bbee082daf62708332df63af9c5b--two-hearts-sweet-hearts.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="img-block__content">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, nihil, sed officiis quas voluptatem sit similique quae ullam neque quod.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Без использования `img` и `JS` необходимо знать пропорции картинки (в следующем примере - 3x1):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  background:url(http://mybk7.ru/assets/images/900x300.png) no-repeat center/contain;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:calc(100% / 3);
}
.block__content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:15px;
}
.block-viewport{
  width:100vw;
  height:calc(100vw / 3);
  padding:15px;
  background:url(http://mybk7.ru/assets/images/900x300.png) no-repeat center/contain;
}
```

```html
<h2>Вариант 1</h2>
<p>Использовать свойство относительного размера вертикального отступа(вычисляется от ширины элемента)</p>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__content">
    <p>asd asd asd asd asd as asd sdasd asd d a</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Вариант 2</h2>
<p>Если элемент занимает 100% ширины экрана - можно использовать единицы viewport</p>
<div class="block-viewport">
  <span>asdasda sd asd asd asd asdasd asda</span>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас решение правильное и рабочее. но оно у вас не на основе блоков а на основе картинок.

Comment: @perfect, то есть использование фоновой картинки обязательно? Предполагается ли в блоках наличие контента? Известны ли заранее пропорции картинки? Допускается использование JS?

Comment: да с контентом, известны только размеры фоновой картинки в пикселях. и без использования JS. На самом деле я хотел бы получить точный ответ на мой вопрос. Если такого решения нет я бы тоже хотел это услышать потому что это тоже является ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял

```css
#first_picture {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6--dahlia-flowers-summer-flowers.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

#second_picture {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/70/32/bb/7032bbee082daf62708332df63af9c5b--two-hearts-sweet-hearts.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="first_picture"></div>
<div id="second_picture"></div>
```

Comment: не то. вы ограничили высоту, а это жесткая привязка к размеру. такого не должно быть. и посмотрите вторую картинку она у вас видна на половину высоты

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так еще

```css
#second_picture {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/753/371608-svetik_2880x1800.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="second_picture"></div>
```